# Forced rerender in Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have v-for

```
        <transition-group
            name="cc"
            tag="div"
            v-masonry
            item-selector=".grid-item"
            column-width=".grid-sizer"
            gutter=".gutter-sizer"
            horizontal-order="true"
            transition-duration="0"
            stagger="0">
        <div class="grid-sizer" :key="-1"></div>
        <div class="gutter-sizer" :key="-2"></div>
        <div v-masonry-tile class="grid-item" v-for="(img, index) in filteredImages" :key="img.id">
            <article v-if="img.type === 2" v-html="img.text">
            </article>
            <a v-if="img.type === 1" @click="startGallery(index, $event)">
                <img-lazy :width="img.width" :height="img.height" :source="'/images/items/' + img.src"
                          :data-index="index" ref="thumbnails"></img-lazy>
            </a>
        </div>
    </transition-group>
```

I filter array in computed with category given in props

```
            filteredImages: function () {
            return this.category === -1 ? this.images : this.images.filter(i => i.category_id === this.category)
        }
```

But after change the category props from -1 (all categories) to 2 (for example), items with category_id equal 2 don't redraw and animations don't apply.

Can you help me?

Comment: you can change the `:key` and vue would create new element. not really sure what you want, though.

Comment: Change to a random number?
I just want the vue to re-render the element or apply animation to it.

Comment: it should work. (but random number may collide, I'd use serial number)

Comment: What besides random numbers?

Comment: vue would reuse elements if possible, change the key is the only public way to force create new element (and make a transition animation) AFAICT.

Comment: alternatively, you could clear this.category completely  and only then add the items again.

Comment: Using serial numbers solved the problem, thx